# Juno: NightLight stopped working

Tags: wingpanel, release-juno

I installed Juno yesterday. Tested nightlight, it was working, but today it is not. I can see the indicator in the wingpanel, can turn it on/off, use the slider, but nothing happens.

Comment: I have tried reinstalling in. downloaded source from github and recompiled. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I needed to change the schedule from "Sunset to Sunrise" to "Manual". I tested to change the hours and it worked again.

Hope that was helpful.